# PowerShell script to get distribution group report

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, microsoft365

I am looking for a PowerShell script to get a export Distribution Group with following Information.

```
Group Display Name
Group Owner
Group Member
Last Activity Date
Member Count 
Received Email Count
Group ID
```

I am working on a script but it is returning error

```
$groupmembers = foreach ($i in Get-DistributionGroup)
 {

    Get-DistributionGroupMember $i | select Display Name, @{n='Member';e={$i.DisplayName}}

}
```

Comment: Please format you code correctly and share the complete error ... formatted as code as well.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This time I have edited the question for you, but please read how to [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) so you can do this yourself next time. Then of course, please respond to the above comments and add your error message in full because _but it is returning error_ doesn't mean anything.

Answer (score 0):

`Get-DistributionGroupMember` returns an [object of type ReducedRecipient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/exchange-server-api/ff346107(v=exchg.150)) which does not contain a fields called `Display` or `Name` - but it does contain a field called `DisplayName` - i think this is probably your issue.

If you dont want to read the docs, an easy way of seeing the members of an object is to use ConvertTo-Json. Temporarily add the line `Get-DistributionGroupMember $i | ConvertTo-Json` inside your foreach loop above the command that is failing. It will output the entire `ReducedRecipient` Object in JSON format so you can easily read the available property names and their current values.